# How do I send a complex JSON object from an HTML form using SYNCHRONOUS page POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, servicestack

My server is using ServiceStack and would like to receive some data like this:

```
{
    Customer: {
        Company: "TheCompany",
        RegionCode: "AU_NSW"
    },
    Name: {
        First: "Jimi",
        Last: "Hendrix"
    }

}
```

I have a form which has these fields and I can easily grab the data using JQuery, make the nested JSON object and use $.post to send it through.

But I don't want to send it as AJAX, because I want the entire page to submit and then the browser to show the server's response as a new page. Just classic form post behaviour.

I have tried embedding the complex json as strings inside hidden form fields - No cigar.

I have also looked to see if ServiceStack has any naming conventions such that I could call my form fields "Name[First]" and have ServiceStack put the right values in their correct nested structure - no cigar on that either.

1. Is there a way I can attach a JSON object to a form's POST data just before that form sends the data through?
   or
2. Is there a way I can do a full page submission with jQuery (so I can send a complex nested JSON whilst still having the normal "page-submit" behaviour)?

Comment: Does your AJAX approach work? If so, can you post the code here so we can see what does work, and make suggestions from that?

Comment: Hello. Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the suggestions. The specs for this project changed a day after I put this question up, so I never tested any solutions - but Scott's looks pretty good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Mythz suggestion of posting JSV values would work, it can sometimes be cumbersome to build and maintain complex JSV in JavaScript. *For example, you may have to deal with escaping user inputted data, and syntax issues can be hard to track*

This solution looks complex but it's really not, and is highly re-usable and only requires that you can send encoded JSON, which from jQuery is very easy.

### [Full Demo Source Code Here](https://gist.github.com/scottmcarthur/11394855)

## Process - How it works:

1. Your jQuery creates the DTO using the form data on submit
2. The DTO is encoded as JSON, simply using `JSON.stringify(data)`
3. The JSON is sent in a hidden form as the value of `Data` field
4. A server DTO attribute filter deserializes the JSON value of `Data` field into your DTO
5. Your service see the DTO populated as normal.

### Filter Attribute:

My solution sends the DTO object encoded as JSON in a form post to the service. Then a simple filter intercepts the request and populates the DTO from the JSON payload.

```cs
public class GetFromJsonVariableAttribute : Attribute, IHasRequestFilter
{
    string _variableName;

    public GetFromJsonVariableAttribute(string variableName = "Data")
    {
        _variableName = variableName;
    }

    public void RequestFilter(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        // Convert the JSON payload to DTO format
        var payload = req.GetParam(_variableName);
        if(payload != null)
            requestDto = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(payload, requestDto.GetType());
    }

    public int Priority { get { return int.MinValue; } }
    IHasRequestFilter IHasRequestFilter.Copy() { return this; }
}
```

#### Usage

Then to use you simply add the attribute to your DTO. `Data` is the name of the form variable that will hold the JSON payload. You can choose any name you want here.

```cs
[GetFromJsonVariable("Data")]
[Route("/Customers","POST")]
public class CreateCustomerRequest : IReturnVoid
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Name Name { get; set; }
}
```

### Client Side (jQuery):

1. Get your form values
2. Build the required DTO structure as a JavaScript object
3. Convert that DTO to a JSON string
4. Set your hidden form value to the DTO string & submit

```js
$("#CreateCustomer").on("submit", function(){

    // Get the form values into simple key value array
    var values = {};
    $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(){ values[this.name] = this.value; });

    // Prepare the DTO
    var data = {
        Customer: {
            Company: values["Company"],
            RegionCode: values["RegionCode"]
        },
        Name: {
            First: values["First"],
            Last: values["Last"]
        }
    };

    // Convert it to JSON
    $('#PayloadForm [name="Data"]').val(JSON.stringify(data));
    $('#PayloadForm').submit();
    return false;
});
```

With the HTML create the form your user will interact with, with no action, but is linked to the jQuery submit event code; And a hidden form that will actually perform the synchronous POST. *Note the attribute `Data` matches that of the attribute the payload should be received on*

```html
<form id="CreateCustomer">
    <input type="text" name="Company" value="TheCompany" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="RegionCode" value="AU_NSW" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="First" value="Jimi" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="Last" value="Hendrix" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<!-- This form is hidden -->
<form action="/Customers" method="POST" id="PayloadForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="Data" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack can [POST complex types using the JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#passing-complex-objects-in-the-query-string), e.g:

```
<input name="Customer" value="{Company:TheCompany,RegionCode:AU_NSW}" />
<input name="Name" value="{First:Jimi,Last:Hendrix}" />
```

Otherwise you can send complex types using JSON, e.g. with jQuery's $.ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   url: "http://host/myservice",
   dataType: 'json',
   data: JSON.stringify({Customer:{Company:'x',RegionCode:'x'}}),
   success: function(response){ ... }
});
```

Although for maximum interoperability you should strive to keep your Request DTO's flat, e.g:

```
<form id="theForm" ...>
  <input name="Company" value="TheCompany" />
  <input name="RegionCode" value="AU_NSW" />
  <input name="FirstName" value="Jimi" />
  <input name="LastName" value="Hendrix" />
</form>
```

Which you can then POST as-is which the browser will do using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-Type, or even ajaxify using [ServiceStack's ss-utils.js bindForm method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/EmailContacts/#binding-html-forms), e.g:

```
$("#theForm").bindForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach a submit handler to the form which places the JSON as the value of a pre-created hidden input field within the form.

```
$(form_to_submit).on('submit', function() {
    $(form_to_submit).find(hidden_input).val(json_value);
});
```

To submit a form using jQuery you use:

```
$(form_to_submit).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing here where I was using NodeJS and an Express Server. I wanted to post a complex JSON object that I had built as the user made selections client side. I then attached an onClick event to a button that called my SubmitForm function.

Your data can be any JSON object. Just be sure to parse it server side.

```
function Param(name, value){
    var hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('name', name);
    hiddenField.setAttribute('value', value);
    return hiddenField;
}

function SubmitForm(data){
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    form.setAttribute('action', '/route');
    form.appendChild(Param('data', JSON.stringify(data)));

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();    
}
```

Additionally, this is pure javascript. No hidden HTML or jQuery here for those of you who prefer to remove the overhead.