# jquery collect data from form into multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, forms

I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

but I have a form, with some divs within containing multiple input, textareas. and I want to collect these into a multidimensional array. kinda like this:

```
{
    "jason" : {
        "name" : "Jason Lengstorf",
        "age" : "24",
        "gender" : "male"
    },
    "kyle" : {
        "name" : "Kyle Lengstorf",
        "age" : "21",
        "gender" : "male"
    }
}
```

but I'm not entirely sure how to do it, and google is not helping.
my html looks like this

```
<form class="testForm" method="POST">

    <div class="uploadForm">
        <input class="uploadedFile" name="form1[]name[]" type="text" value="myname" />
        <input class="uploadedFile" name="form1[]phone[]" type="text" value="2019192" />
        <input class="uploadedFile" name="form1[]text[]" type="text" value="sometext" />
    </div>

    <div class="uploadForm">
        <input class="uploadedFile" name="form2[]name[]" type="text" value="myname" />
        <input class="uploadedFile" name="form2[]phone[]" type="text" value="2019192" />
        <input class="uploadedFile" name="form2[]text[]" type="text" value="sometext" />
    </div>


    <button>save</button>
</form>
```

and the script collecting

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $(".testForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        var $form = $(this);

        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

        var serializedData = $form.serializeArray();
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        alert(JSON.stringify(serializedData));

        })

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're going to have to use `serializeArray` and then format the data yourself, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send a complex JSON object from an HTML form using SYNCHRONOUS page POST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23355017/how-do-i-send-a-complex-json-object-from-an-html-form-using-synchronous-page-pos)

Comment: As i can see from the fiddle demo, i only get the array in one level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SerializeJSON works really well for what you're trying to achieve here.

https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON

Comment: This is a great plugin and a good answer. @bymem See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/ty3nj064/) for serializeJSON and it works as you wanted it. I had only to rename the objects to meet your requirement.

Comment: this kinda help me, i went with another plugin. They do the same thing. So thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First I would try usind id's `<form class="testForm" method="POST" id="testForm">`

then use:

`var formData = JSON.stringify($("#testForm").serializeArray());`

you will get a json out of your form