# Creating dynamic nested json object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need an JSON object of following structure:

```js
tableNames = [{
  "tableName1": "string1",
  "tableName2": "string2",
  "joinConditions": [{
    "tableColumn1": "string1",
    "tableColumn2": "String2"
  }]
}]
```

how do you think my html should be designed. can anybody help me with frontend html code and js for this. I need this json object on submitting a page. imagine there is an empty json object is present in javascript code.

Comment: You are missing a square bracket at the end of the declaration. **Edit:** Rajesh edited it, now it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23360717/1839272

Since it looks like you want to submit tables-names to create a database-query based on a form. I recommend not to do so, unless your user know what they do. At least do some sort of syntax-check.